# Not able to find a question I posted

Tags: support, reputation, answers, deleted-questions

I posted a question 1 week back, and it had a few upvotes and answers. But I'm not able to find the question in my profile now (and I've lost the reputation points I've gained from that question). How do I find out if it has been removed or moved or closed?

Comment: If you can't find it in your profile, it has been deleted.

Comment: I believe this might be the question you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973275/code-coverage-tool-for-c-and-java

Comment: It appears to have been closed and deleted for being a shopping list question.

Answer (score 7):

Check the 'show removed posts' checkbox at the bottom of your [reputation overview](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441575/raj?tab=reputation).

If the post was removed, you'll see a negative score (in red) together with the title of the deleted question and the word `removed`:

[image: removed posts]